# JavaScript Promise Chaining- Why not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

In the following code, can someone explain why calling `secondMethod` in the Promise chain works but calling `secondMethod()` does not?

```
function firstMethod() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('first method completed');
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
};


function secondMethod() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('second method completed');
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
};

function thirdMethod() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('third method completed');
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
};

// Works
firstMethod().then(secondMethod).then(thirdMethod);

// Doesn't work - executes secondMethod immediately after firstMethod
// firstMethod().then(secondMethod()).then(thirdMethod);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your research.

Comment: You need to pass the whole function as a parameter...when you pass `function()` as the parameter you are invoking the functions and passing the promise as parameter, something that no makes a lot of sense...when you work with promises and you use `then` you want to call the next function once your first promise get resolved and so on....

Comment: I see, so what if I want to call my `secondFunction` with a parameter once my `firstFunction` resolves? Say `secondFunction('1234')`? How should I do this?

Comment: @lo234081 for that, you would either need two functions so `first.then(() => second('1234'))` or you could bind the arguments through closure or via [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): `first.then(second.bind(null, '1234'))`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes one or two callbacks. It does not take a Promise.

When you immediately call `secondMethod` you're passing a Promise to `.then`.

It's essentially the same as doing this:

```
firstMethod()
  .then(new Promise(...)) // Should be a function, not a Promise
```

Answer (score 3):

The second way doesn't work because you're calling the functions immediately, in a synchronous way, before any of the timeouts resolve.

Here's another way to think about what's happening:

```
// you're calling all your methods and creating promises before creating the chain
let first = firstMethod();
let second = secondMethod();
let third = thirdMethod();

first.then(second).then(third);
```

Comment: @alexmac That would be a correct way of writing it (assuming you meant `secondMethod()` etc. You can't call a promise as a function). Even shorter would be `first.then(secondMethod).then(thirdMethod)`. I believe nem035  is showing what's *wrong* with OPs approach.

Comment: @Mike C, yup, that's exactly what I'm doing. The OP already has a correct answer in his question